# href is empty, how to get the URL?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I was using Python/Scrapy. When I try to find the URL of a “next page” button, I find the `href` attribute of the button is empty. And the button works. Is it possible to get the link by an xPath or CSS selector?

The HTML is like this:

```html
<a data-testid="pagination-next-page" class="button small right shadowbox no-margin" ng-click="togglePage(page + 1)" href=""><span>Seuraava</span> <i class="icon-OT4-19"></i></a>
```

Comment: something lie this? `a[href=""]`

Comment: The answer's going to depend completely on how that site implemented the "next page" button. Presumably there's javascript driving it, but determining which bit of code sets the url will take some studying of their source code (or just trigger a click on it and seeing where it leads.)

Comment: well, yes I can have the link when I click the button. However, scrapy needs the href as a source to automatically do the 'next page ' web crawling. So it would be great if I can get the link from somewhere else than the browser address bar .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the link by an xPath or CSS selector?

No.

That link is using [an AngularJS click handler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick):

```
ng-click="togglePage(page + 1)"
```

This will call a function named `togglePage()`. Tracing what this function does will require some digging -- analyzing it automatically is essentially impossible.